# How to get the value of a key in firebase - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so this is an image of my JSON tree:
[my JSON TREE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtiIL.png)

Question:
I wanted to know how can I check if the username, let's say, **sean** exists in the `usernames`. I currently have no idea on how to implement this.

What I've tried:
The key of `usernames` child is "theUsernameOf-`userUID`", and that causes the problem as `userUID` is dynamic and different from each user (from firebase auth), therefore I can't use:

`.queryOrderedByChild("theUsernameOf-userUID").queryEqual(toValue: self.usernameTextBox.text!)`

The key of `usernames` child can't be static like `theUsername` as it would only be able to have 1 value / not able to generate more node.

Thank you so much, sorry if I didn't explain clearly enough.

Comment: You have to fetch all values from  node "usernames".Then you can iterate through all keys to to get its value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to modify your DB structure as current one is not the correct to perform this query.

**It should be like below:**

[image]

Always use auto incremented keys for queries. Here `usernames -> autoGeneratedKey -> yourData (Dictionary - Key-Value pair)` Now you can easily check the existence of any key.

```
let ref = defaultDB.reference.child("usernames")
ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "sean").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print("exists")
    }
    else {
        print("doesn't exist")
    }
}
```

> **Output:** exists

This is the correct way to do so. Just checking for `snapshot.exists()` will do the job for you.

Comment: this worked! I didn't realise that queryOrdered(byChild: ) can be used like that. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it

1. Set the database reference to the usernames node. For example `db.ref.child("usernames")`
2. Now parse the snapshot using for loop
   let usernames = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
3. Now the for loop

   ```
   for username in usernames{
        if username.value == "Sean"{
         // do whatever you want here
       }
     }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could also:

Make a firebase call to `usernames` and make that:

`let usernames = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]`, 
then all you have to do is something like

`if let keyExists = usernames[YOURUSERNAMECHECKSTRING] { 
//It's true 
}`

Just another way of looking at it.

Comment: `NSDictionary` in Swift ? Don't do this.

Comment: You can use Swift’s dictionary as well.

Comment: Even you should always use `Swift` dictionary in `Swift`.

Comment: Updated for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you observe any reference in firebase, you get a `DataSnapshot` in return. The **snapshot** has a `children` enumerator property on which you can enumerate each child. Each of the child will be another `DataSnapshot`. Now, each **snapshot** has `key` and `value`. You want the user name? It's in the `value` property:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "usernames")
databaseRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    snapshot.children.forEach({ (child) in
        if let child = child as? DataSnapshot, let value = child.value {
            print(value)    //"Sean", "Yuh"
            // here you can check for your desired user
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This code will Help you you dont need to change your firebase structure

1. In Swift

   ```
   Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").queryOrdered(byChild: "usernames").queryEqual(toValue: "yourUserName").observe(.value)
      { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in

         if snapshot.valueInExportFormat() is NSDictionary
         {
                   // User is exits
         }
         else
         {

         }
      }
   ```
2. In Objective c

   ```
   [[[[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"users"] queryOrderedByChild:@"usernames"] queryEqualToValue:@"your User Name"] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot)
   {
    if ([snapshot.valueInExportFormat isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        // User is exits
    }
    else
    {
    }
   }];
   ```